# Get All Items including Disabled Products in Product Collection

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, products, product-collection

I want to get all products including disabled and enabled in one of my static page.

I am fetching product collection like

```
$videoProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer_value', array('in' => array($brand)))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_option', 0);
```

Where `$brand` is an array of multiple ids'.
To get all products I read somewhere to disable relation between product flat table.

It does not work for me to set "NO" to catalog flat table relation under magento admin panel.

Anyone let me know if I can get it via `getCollection()` method.

Comment: Could you update your answer with the output of the `$videoProduct->getSelectSql(true)`?

Answer (score 1):

`$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();`

Note that for getting all the products including the Disabled product you have to

Change the config `Use Flat Catalog Product` to `"NO"`.

You will find the settings in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend`

Answer (score 0):

if you look to the core source code in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php::_initSelect()

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
        $this->getSelect()
            ->from(array(self::MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS => $this->getEntity()->getFlatTableName()), null)
            ->where('e.status = ?', new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
        $this->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id', 'type_id', 'attribute_set_id'));
        if ($this->getFlatHelper()->isAddChildData()) {
            $this->getSelect()
                ->where('e.is_child = ?', 0);
            $this->addAttributeToSelect(array('child_id', 'is_child'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->getSelect()->from(array(self::MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS => $this->getEntity()->getEntityTable()));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

you can see that the filter on enabled products is only present when the catalog flat product feature in enabled.

So, it is strange that disabling it is not working for you. (maybe the source code is not the same as mine or you have already a rewrite of this class)

But, in case you want to use this "catalog flat product" feature, I think the simple way is to use a rewrite of the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection and change the method _initSelect().

Hope it will help.

Best Regards